# java.io.EOFException at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.read(TCPNIOTransport.java:607)

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, multipartform-data

I'm getting this exception in my Servlet class, when I'm trying to upload file from client app to my server, this is my servlet doPost code fragment

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String userName = "admin";
        String password = "123";
        if (DBManager.getInstance().checkIfCanLogin(userName, password)) {

            final Part part = (Part) request.getParts().toArray()[1];
            new Thread(() -> {
                // bla bla bla 
            }).start();
        } else {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

here the line `final Part part = (Part) request.getParts().toArray()[1];` throws exception, I'm trying to fix this problem hole day but nothing found, also I'm new in JavaEE, my background is from android, also what I'm trying to understan is that everything worked properly, but after restarting (I think nothing more have done with it) this Servlet stoped working, problem has only this servlet, where I'm sending files from client (andorid using **retrofit**)

this is error log

```
 [2017-05-02T18:45:45.472+0400] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=29 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1493736345472] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  java.io.EOFException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.read(TCPNIOTransport.java:607)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTemporarySelectorReader.readNow0(TCPNIOTemporarySelectorReader.java:65)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read0(TemporarySelectorReader.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read0(TemporarySelectorReader.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:75)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.AbstractReader.read(AbstractReader.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleRead(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleRead(TransportFilter.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.read(DefaultFilterChain.java:351)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.read(FilterChainContext.java:736)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.blockingRead(InputBuffer.java:1107)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.io.ServerInputBuffer.blockingRead(ServerInputBuffer.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.fill(InputBuffer.java:1131)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:888)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.fileupload.Streams.copy(Streams.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.fileupload.Streams.copy(Streams.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.fileupload.Multipart.initParts(Multipart.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.fileupload.Multipart.getParts(Multipart.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:4507)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1086)
    at servlet.UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:36)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)]]
```